# I can see the source for the pages in my Mediawiki wiki, but not the pages: how can I fix this?

Tags: mediawiki

I maintain a wiki for a non-profit that teaches computing skills to people with disabilities. The wiki has run okay since about 2006, but for some reason when I last visited it all of the pages were blank.

I can still log in to the wiki and view the revision history for each page; I can also view the source for each page, and it's absolutely fine: it's just that the pages themselves are not displayed. Instead, I just get the boilerplate that is present on every page in the wiki, and the title of that page.

What's the best way to get started on troubleshooting this?

Comment: Do you have **php installed/configured?** That is generally the only reason you get source instead of formatted pages... To test, at the shell prompt on your server try: `echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' | php`

Comment: Also check your server logs and see if something mysterious is going on there.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think he is referring to the wiki source here (as he can see revision history).

Jim: Do you have a link?

Comment: That's correct, Leo. http://wiki.ucandoit.org.uk

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is correct, [the wikitext is there](/?oldid=1&action=edit) but it's [not parsed at all](http://wiki.ucandoit.org.uk/api.php?action=parse&oldid=1).

I visited a few random pages and I saw you have some spam cleanup to do, at least [on some pages](/?diff=5654&oldid=3962). Additionally, [I see](http://wiki.ucandoit.org.uk/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=general%7Cnamespaces%7Cnamespacealiases%7Cstatistics%7Cextensions%7Crightsinfo%7Cskins%7Cextensiontags%7Cfunctionhooks%7Cshowhooks) that you installed the MaintenanceShell extension, which is a serious danger because a successful attacker might do almost anything with your files.

So, it seems to me quite likely that your wiki code was cracked and the parsing currently fails. Just backup the whole installation directory, delete it, follow normal [[mediawikiwiki:Manual:Upgrade]] instructions to install latest MediaWiki core code (from the tarball) over a clean directory. You have to do it anyway, because we are at 1.24 and you still have 1.19.1, which is unsupported. Hopefully, no more damage was done.